# Display Checkboxes Horizontally

Tags: react-native, checkbox, expo, react-native-stylesheet

I imported some custom checkboxes but they're displaying vertically and I want them to be displayed horizontally in a row

I tried changing the flex-direction and some other things but none of that has changed anything.
Here is my code:

```
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const CheckBox = (props) => {
  const iconName = props.isChecked
    ? "checkbox-marked"
    : "checkbox-blank-outline";

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable onPress={props.onPress}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={40} color="#000" />
      </Pressable>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CheckBox;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: 150,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#000a",
    textAlign: "left",
    top: 50,
    marginTop: 40,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hello! Changing the 'flexDirection' from 'column' to 'row' (in the 'container' style) should display the icon and the title side, no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `flexDirection` from `column` to `row`. Furthermore, you need to remove the `topMargin` from the `title` style for otherwise the checkbox and the text won't be aligned.

The adapted styles:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: 150,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#000a",
  },
});
```

The final product:

[image]

Comment: That didn't work. I need the actual textboxes to appear side by side in a row. I have 7 checkboxes(one for each day of the week) and need them to be displayed horizontally

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by just updating your CSS  like this in your container stylesheet class  :
{

```
flexDirection: "row",
Display:in-line,
float:left,
```

},